# select rows if column contain name elements, any order

Tags: regex, postgresql, sql-like, string-matching

I have a table that contains a few thousands rows. These results have been produced by querying an api with a list of names.

For a search of "John Snow" the api would return all entries in their database which contained the token "john" and the token "snow". So I have a lot of false positives.

What I would like to do is to subset my table so that the I only have records where the column `title` (the one which contained the string matched against my search string) contains ALL elements of the searched string, **regardless of the order**.

I tried

`select * from table where 'john snow' ~* title;`

`select * from table where 'john snow' ILIKE '%' || title || '%';`

both work but only if the column `title` contains exactly `john snow` in that order.

Before

```
str_searched |  title
-------------+-------
john snow    | snow white
john snow    | john wick
john snow    | SNOW john
john snow    | john Snow
john snow    | Mr john snow
```

After

```
str_searched |  title
-------------+-------
john snow    | SNOW john
john snow    | john Snow
john snow    | Mr john snow
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=f1b8510cd3515e6c829a1e233a9080d3)

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    my_table
WHERE
    regexp_split_to_array(lower('john snow'), ' ') 
        <@ regexp_split_to_array(lower(title), ' ')
```

1. `lower()` normalizes the capital letters
2. `regexp_split_to_array()` tranforms the text into an array at the space
3. Now you have 2 arrays which can be compared (e.g. `[john,snow]` and `[mr,john,snow]`). The `<@` comparator checks if the left array is complete contained by the right one.

---

Disclaimer: On really huge tables this might be slow. In that case I would recommend to take a look a the full text search engine: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! It did the job perfectly, and I learnt how and why. Thanks again.